# How to make a column in QTableWidget read only?

Tags: qt, qt4, qtablewidget

I would like to have one column in `QTableWidget` *NOT* editable.
In forums I have read a lot about some `flags` but could not manage to implement.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Insert into the QTableWidget following kind of items:

```
QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem();
item->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsSelectable|Qt::ItemIsEnabled);
```

Works fine!

EDIT:

```
QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem();
item->setFlags(item->flags() ^ Qt::ItemIsEditable);
```

This is a better solution. Thanks to @priomsrb.

Comment: It would be better to use `item->setFlags(item->flags() ^ Qt::ItemIsEditable);`. This will leave the other flags intact

Comment: @priomsrb Why do you use an exclusive or (XOR) instead of `item->flags() &  ~Qt::ItemIsEditable` as suggested by user2923436? The result of XOR depends on the default state of the flags.

Comment: @m7913d I think you're right. My solution just toggles the editable state. So it wouldn't work if the item was already read only.

Answer (score 52):

The result of using XOR depends on what the current state is. I'd suggest using

```
item->setFlags(item->flags() &  ~Qt::ItemIsEditable);
```

to make sure editing is turned off regardless of the current setting.

Comment: I tried this solution of yours and it didn't work: the compiler complained about the '~'.

Comment: `~` is bitwise negation and should be supported by all compilers.

Answer (score 2):

I came to a better suggestion, just overwrite the cellDoubleClicked signal with a new SLOT.
This is, if you want none of the cells to be modified

Comment: No need to do that, that's why we have item flags. Just one line to fix his problem.

Comment: The difference is you would have to exclude the flag from the bitmap on all his child items?. My suggestion was to exclude writing 20 lines with &~ bitmap flag if you want the entire widget to be readonly. Actually my comment was wrong anyway, it should say disconnect the cellDoubleClicked signal

Answer (score 0):

To apply @Narek's code to rows or columns, simply use a simple for loop and put a condition in to include the flags for rows/columns you do not want to be editable.

The following code reads a csv file into a QTableWidget:

```
if(!rowOfData.isEmpty()){
for (int x = 0; x < rowOfData.size(); x++)
    {
        rowData = rowOfData.at(x).split(",");
        if(ui->table_Data->rowCount() <= x) ui->table_Data->insertRow(x);
        for (int y = 0; y < rowData.size(); y++)
        {
            QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem(rowData[y],QTableWidgetItem::Type);
            if( y < 3 ) item->setFlags(item->flags() ^ Qt::ItemIsEditable);   // Only disables the first three columns for editing, but allows the rest of the columns to be edited
            ui->table_Data->setItem(x,y,item);
            ui->table_Data->repaint();
        }
    }
}
```