# how to make a cell in a QTableWidget read only?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, qtablewidget

i have the following code defining the gui of my app

```
class Ui (object):
    def setupUi():
        self.tableName = QtGui.QTableWidget(self.layoutWidget_20)
        self.tableName.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("twHistoricoDisciplinas"))
        self.tableName.setColumnCount(4)
        self.tableName.setRowCount(3)
```

and the following code in my app

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ui = Ui()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.createtable()

    #creating a tw cell
    def cell(self,var=""):
            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
            item.setText(var)
            return item

    def createtable(self):
         rows = self.tableName.rowCount()
         columns = self.tableName.columnCount()
         for i in range(rows):
             for j in range(columns):
                 item = self.cell("text")
                 self.ui.tableName.setItem(i, j, item)
```

I want to be able to add new rows and columns and edit them but i want to lock some of the cells. ( i already have code that expand the table ) 
how can i make some cells read only while keeping the others read write?
i found this link [How to make a column in QTableWidget read only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574115/) with a solution for the problem in C++, is python solution similar ?

EDIT: Removed the answer from the post and pasted as an answer

Comment: There is usually very few differencies between the c++ and the python code with Qt. You just have to adjust the syntax and this piece of code will work like a charm.

Comment: @madjar ...it really did work like a charm :), i just needed to find where were declared the flags, i´m new to python and qt, it takes some time to get used to it

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I played a little with the code and read some more documentation
the answer to the problem is

```
def createtable(self):
     rows = self.tableName.rowCount()
     columns = self.tableName.columnCount()
     for i in range(rows):
         for j in range(columns):
             item = self.cell("text")
             # execute the line below to every item you need locked
             item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
             self.ui.tableName.setItem(i, j, item)
```

---

The solution is the line "item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)", you use it to set the cell property QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled to disabled, so you can't select or edit the cell

You can change a number of other properties this way at runtime as per documentarion on http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qt.html under the section Qt::ItemFlag

as mentioned in a comment by Sven on the second answer to this question, if you have a static number of rows and columns in your QTableWidgetItem you can select the properties of the cells with Qtdesigner if you use it to create the screens for your application

Comment: This works because you are wiping out the other flags when you set `Qt.ItemIsEnabled`.

Answer (score 25):

The editing status of a QTableWidgetItem is never entered when there are no Edit Triggers:

`self.tableName.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)`

Comment: This can also be set in the Qt Designer via clicking.

Comment: But what if I want the ability for copy but not edit?

Comment: @walksignison You can still click on the cells to mark them and then press "Ctrl + C". The content of the marked cell will be put into the clipboard.

Answer (score 22):

Like [Sven Krüger's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7545157/sven-kr%C3%BCger) answer, you can also use this methods for **PyQt5**:

```
self.tableWidget.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QTableWidget.NoEditTriggers)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want the UI to look the same (have it still selectable, and turn blue, but just not editable) I found `QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable` gave good results.

```
item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
item.setFlags(item.flags() ^ QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
self.table_widget.setItem(row, column, item)
```

Comment: This answer is the most correct. You shouldn't set the flag like the other answers, where you remove all the other flags. At the same time, you can add " ^ Qt.ItemIsSelectable" or  " ^ Qt.ItemIsEnabled" to make the item unselectable or disable it.

Answer (score 3):

For PyQt6, it's the same as @ozcanyarimdunya but with the enum `EditTrigger`:

```
self.tableWidget.setEditTriggers(QTableWidget.EditTrigger.NoEditTriggers)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

if you want to make the whole table is not editable try this:

```
for row in range(self.tableName.rowCount()):
    for col in range(self.tableName.columnCount()):
        self.tableName.item(row,col).setFlags(Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEditable)
```