# PyQt5 QTableWidget: make last column editable

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

How do you access the last column of a QTableWidget? I want to set it to editable using something like this:

```
item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(stuff)
item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled) #make everything editable
self.qtable_widget.setItem(row, column, item)
```

Answer (score 1):

To modify the editing ability of item groups then it is better to use a delegate as show in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56883479/6622587), this question is slightly different so I have modified my solution:

```py
class ReadOnlyDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        # last column
        if index.column() == (index.model().columnCount() - 1):
            return super().createEditor(parent, option, index)
```

```
delegate = ReadOnlyDelegate(self.qtable_widget)
self.qtable_widget.setItemDelegate(delegate)
```