# qt designer certain columns of a QTableWidget editable

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtablewidget

i have a QTableWidget created with Qt Designer and would like to know if it is possible to
make certain columns editable and other not in Qt designer. I have seen solutions in python
or c++ but i would like to know if it is possible in qt designer.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to do it with Qt Designer since at most you can make the items created by QtDesigner non-editable (the items are editable by default) and not the new rows or columns created by code. So the simplest and most practical solution is to do it by code using a delegate as I point out in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61386219/pyqt5-qtablewidget-make-last-column-editable/61387354#61387354):

```
class ReadOnlyDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editable_columns = (1, 3, 4)
        if index.column() in editable_columns:
            return super().createEditor(parent, option, index)
```

```
delegate = ReadOnlyDelegate(self.qtable_widget)
self.tableWidget.setItemDelegate(delegate)
```

Answer (score 1):

For a whole column, I don't think so. No flags are provided in the properties for the columns. If your table isn't too big, you could edit the items individually like so:

In the Designer, right-click the `QTAbleWidget` and click on `Edit Items...`. Then, switch over to the `Items` tab.

From there, click on any item and then open up the `Properties <<` tab. In there you should find a checkbox for whether that specific item is editable or not.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unf that wont do. I want the user be able to enter a product id and then the rest of the row is populated automatically, like description, price etc. the other fields in the row should not be editable.