# Qt - How can I make a particular Column of my QTableView as Non Editable?

Tags: c++, qt, delegates, qtableview, qt4.7

I have a `QTableView` with 4 Rows and 4 columns each representing their data's in it.  By default the `QTableView` is editable. Now I want to make any particular column as non editable in my `QTableView`.

How can I do it?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the [`setItemDelegateForColumn()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegateForColumn) function. Implement a read-only delegate, and set it for the column you need.

You can also use [the flags](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qabstractitemmodel.html#flags) inside your model, and remove the `Qt::ItemIsEditable` flag for a specific column.

Answer (score 12):

Something like that may also do it:

```
class NotEditableDelegate : public QItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit NotEditableDelegate(QObject *parent = 0)
        : QItemDelegate(parent)
    {}

protected:
    bool editorEvent(QEvent *event, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index)
    { return false; }
    QWidget* createEditor(QWidget *, const QStyleOptionViewItem &, const QModelIndex &) const
    { return Q_NULLPTR; }

};
```

In use:

```
// Make all the columns except the second read only
for(int c = 0; c < view->model()->columnCount(); c++)
{
    if(c != 1)
        view->setItemDelegateForColumn(c, new NotEditableDelegate(view));
}
```

Comment: Retrurning true instead of false in editorEvent will prevent createEditor from being called at all, as it consumes the event at that point.

Comment: @ricekab I'm not sure that is true: the doc says "The base implementation returns false (indicating that it has not handled the event)." and according to an experiment I just did returning false for a given `index.colum()` did not stop the editing.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is settting the flag of the item you don't want to be editable in this way:

```
item->setFlags(item->flags() &  ~Qt::ItemIsEditable);
```

You can also check this thread: [Qt How to make a column in QTableWidget read only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574115/qt-how-to-make-a-column-in-qtablewidget-read-only/19609548#19609548)

Comment: This method works for QTableWidges, but not for QTableViews, which is what the question is asking about.

Comment: Works on QTableView , Qt 4.8.4. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the overide method just change it to `if(!(index.column() == 0)` and change the `Flag` value as `Flag |= Qt::ItemisEditable`.
This Works Fine.

Comment: I guess you meant overriding `bool QAbstractItemView::edit(const QModelIndex & index, EditTrigger trigger, QEvent * event)` didn't you?
In such case you can just return `false` for read-only column.

Answer (score 1):

May be this late, but for future reference. You should set the table view to `NoEditTrigger` like this:

```
myTableView->setModel(model);
myTableView->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers)
```

Comment: Wow, that's the cleanest solution I've seen up to now, especially if you only want the data to be read-only in _one_ of your views on the same model. Thanks!

Comment: But how can this method be applied to a single column or row, as OP asks?

Answer (score 1):

You need to *override* the *'flags'* method and specify the editability parameters of the element for the selected column

```
Qt::ItemFlags TableModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if(!index.isValid())
        return Qt::NoItemFlags;
    if(index.column() == SELECTED_COLUMN_NUM)
    {
        return Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable;
    }
    return Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable | Qt::ItemIsEditable;
}
```