# unable to set text in qtablewidget cells

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I want to have a read only text in `QTableWidget`, so I decided to insert a `QLabel` in each cell. Unfortunately I'm getting the following look:

[image]

Here is the code that I use for this:

```
for (int row = 1; row < ui->currentSetting1TableWidget->rowCount(); row++)
    for (int col = 1; col < ui->currentSetting1TableWidget->colorCount(); col++) {
        QLabel *label = new QLabel(ui->currentSetting1TableWidget);
        label->setText("mytext");
        ui->currentSetting1TableWidget->setCellWidget(row, col, label);
    }
```

I see two issues:

1. When I run the code I got a bunch of the following warnings:
   QPaintDevice::metrics: Device has no metric information
2. **`mytext`** is displayed in the corner header cell. Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: Check the accepted answer of the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574115/how-to-make-a-column-in-qtablewidget-read-only
I think it may help you

Comment: If you think of using a `QLabel` in any of the views, you're doing it wrong. The view already supports displaying text and images just like `QLabel` does. Item attributes set the behavior of each data item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ui->currentSetting1TableWidget->colorCount()` you have code-completion-assisted typo. You wanted [`columnCount()`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.8/qtablewidget.html#columnCount-prop). Because you specify incorrect placement for additional (`colorCount()` must be higher than `columnCount()`) labels they're assigned to coordinates (0,0) or something very close.

You're also iterating from `row = 1`, but rows are indexed from 0, that's why you don't have labels in the first row. It makes sense to skip first column and iterate them from `1`, because of the checkboxes.

Comment: @flashburn there's also no need for a label because you can set the column to non editable with QFlags / use QTableWidgetItem

Comment: @deW1 Can you expand on "use QTableWidgetItem"? What do you mean by it?

Comment: @flashburn https://gist.github.com/deW1/2ebfadaefc7c5682b2896e6d8b540417 for example

Comment: That's a nice use of xor

Comment: yup and by wrapping an if around it you could set conditions for table fields that you want to keep editable by not changing the flags

Comment: OMG, I just made the same exact typo! This is ridiculous :D  I got this weird message out of nowhere and googled "QPaintDevice::metrics: Device has no metric information" and the first link was this question, and it turned out I too wrote `colorCount()` instead of `columnCount()`. Thank you so much and I wish to everyone who reads this that all mysterious bugs would be solved this easily! :D