# Qt: avoid add text to empty cell in QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I have `QTableWidget` with specific row and column. When I click on empty cell a text opens and let user to write on cell. Is there any way to avoid this situation, I mean, to avoid adding text on empty cell?

**UPDATE:** 
I added this part to slot of `cellclick()`, but empty cells are yet editable,

```
QTableWidgetItem *item = filesTable->item(row, column);
item->setFlags(item->flags() & ~Qt::ItemIsEditable);
```

Is there any way to force empty cells to be read-only?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a column in QTableWidget read only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574115/how-to-make-a-column-in-qtablewidget-read-only)

Comment: @Steeve , I updated my question according the link you mentianed.