# How to make QTableWidget cells read only using PYQT5?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a QTableWidget in my dialog. I want to make some cells read only. How do I do that using PYQT5?

Comment: I thought this was a dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574115/how-to-make-a-column-in-qtablewidget-read-only), but that is about columns, not cells.

Answer (score 3):

To make particular cell of a QTableWidget read only:

```
item = QTableWidgetItem()
item.setFlags(item.flags() ^ Qt.ItemIsEditable)
tableName.setItem(row, column, item)
```

Just change flags to change the behavior/properties of the cell.

Reference answer is [@Narek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574115/how-to-make-a-column-in-qtablewidget-read-only)

Answer (score 0):

The below code can set a specific QTableWidget cell item as read-only for PyQt5. The cell item can be assigned before being set as read-only.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

cell_item = tableWidget.item(i, j)
cell_item .setFlags(cell_item.flags() ^ Qt.ItemIsEditable)
```